# C++ How to check if string starts with char from input

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char

So I want to make a console application that asks you one letter, and a word, and to see if word starts with that letter.

```
    cout<<"Player 1: "<<endl;
    cin>> letter;
    cin>> word1;
    std::string s(word1);

    if (s.find(letter) == 0){
        std::cout << "String starts with "<< letter<< endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and descrive the expected behavior.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. I imagine you are not here just to tell a cool story.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is, but I suspect that you're messing up the types.

Comment: What is the problem? https://ideone.com/B3AAZy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access first element of the string:

```
std::string someString = "foo"; // for example purposes
char someChar = 'f';

if (someString[0] == someChar)
    std::cout << "First character of this string is " << someChar << "!";
```

Be careful though, if you fail to read string, you can try to access the first element (with index 0) but it may not exist. Do it like this:

```
if (someString.length() > 0)
{
    // string is not empty. You can use also !someString.empty()
}
```

Comment: The thing is that (supposing `letter` is a `char`) the original code also works, in a complicated way. `find` will tell you the position of `letter`, if any, and if that is 0 it *is* the first position.